# How to map both keys and values of a mapping?

Tags: isabelle

I need to define a function which maps keys and values of a finite map into a set of key-value pairs:

```
theory Test
  imports Main "~~/src/HOL/Library/Finite_Map"
begin

definition denorm :: "('a, 'b) fmap ⇒ ('a × 'b) fset" where
  "denorm m ≡ "

end
```

The problem is that I can't define this function by recursion, because `fmap` isn't an inductive data type and it doesn't have any constructors.

I guess that `fmap` is represented as a list of pairs internally. Is it possible to convert `fmap` to the list? I need an inverse of `fmap_of_list` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to compose image, domain, and lookup: the expression

```
λ m. (λ k. (k, the (fmlookup m k))) |`| fmdom m
```

has the desired type

```
('a, 'b) fmap ⇒ ('a × 'b) fset
```

and should compute the desired set for a map `m`.

Answer (score 1):

This function is already there:

```
fset_of_fmap :: "('a, 'b) fmap ⇒ ('a × 'b) fset"
```

Comment: I can't find it in Isabelle2016-1. Maybe it in the latest unstable version?

Comment: Yeah, I added it for 2017, of which the first release candidate is available.